# Execution Exception with @inputDate when call form.get() method

Tags: playframework-2.1, executionexception

I have a input of date type. The attribute is like this:

```
@Formats.DateTime(pattern="dd/MM/yyyy")
public Date prazo;
```

In the `*.scala.html` file, I tried this:

```
@helper.input(pedidoForm("prazo"), '_label -> "Prazo", '_help -> "") { (id, name, value, args) => 
    <input type="date" name="@name" id="@id" maxlength="14" @toHtmlArgs(args)>
}
```

and

```
@inputDate(pedidoForm("prazo"), '_label -> "Prazo", '_help -> "")
```

It compiles and seems to work fine, but in the controller I have something like:

```
Form<Pedido> pedidoForm = form(Pedido.class).bindFromRequest();
...
pedidoForm.get(); // throws execution exception
```

Does anyone have an idea of what can be happening??

Thanks for the attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have entered wrong format for date input.

Form what I have tried. If you entered `22/03/1989` as value of input, there is no runtime exception. But if you entered `22 03 1989`, the exception is occurred. I think it is because you define the `prazo` field as `dd/MM/yyyy` date format.

So let's we look again. If you define the `prazo` field as `dd MM yyyy` date format, and you entered value `22 03 1989` as value of input, there is no runtime exception. In addition, there something that interested me, if you entered `22/03/1989` there is no runtime exception too. But, with the date you entered previously, **it cannot be parsed correctly**.

In this stage, I think the framework accept value like `dd/MM/yyyy` as a `Date` object. But if you want other date format displayed or entered the `@Formats.DateTime(pattern="dd MM yyyy")` annotation **should be** used.